# Facebook Share Button equal to Twitter Tweet Button

Tags: buttons, css, facebook

I made a working Twitter "Tweet" button through: https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet (which indeed does appear on my site on localhost) and really need a Facebook "Share" button that matches it in color scheme, font type/color, and highlight effects.

However, the blue button does not seem editable by CSS (just as Twitter's doesn't). Would love some help/direction about how to make these match.

*EDIT - I removed the first part of the question and just left the UX portion for this site. Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be off topic because it has to do with code not working correctly. Question should be migrated to [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Funny, they told me to post it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273068/facebook-share-button-equal-to-twitter-tweet-button

Comment: Yea, your question is really two parts.  One is the non-functioning FB code and the blue button not being editable, which is a question for SO.  However, after that's solved, the first paragraph sounds like it would be more suited here at UX in that you want help making Twitter and Facebook icons to match.  So maybe edit both questions, the one on SO to fix the code issues and this one here to figure out how to make the icons match.

Comment: @CodeMaverick The OP doesn't appear to have any doubts over whether it would be good UX for the icons to match. That part of the post does *not* appear to be in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter and Facebook buttons are *intended* to be different and it would be against either Twitter's and Facebook's branding guides to make them look similarly/the same. I also think it would be a bad idea to modify the original buttons, since people recognize them *because they are the same on every other website* - so if you change them, it may happen so noone will ever click these buttons for at least one reason: they may appear scam. Anyway, see https://www.facebookbrand.com/ and https://about.twitter.com/press/brand-assets

Comment: Thanks for link to Facebook icon. The reason that I can't use the blue Facebook button is that my background is similarly blue and it would be camouflaged, so I'm guessing they'd rather have the button be visible than unmodified.